# JsError while trying to parse JSON file into case class with Play framework API in Scala

Tags: scala, play-json

I'm currently trying to parse a JSON file composed of an array of json rows to create an Array of Message (which is my case class). I'm using Play API to deal with my JSON file. Using [this documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) from Play documentation, I can't figure out what I'm missing...

My json file is as following :

```
    [
  {
    "pwId": 11,
    "pwLong": "1.462734",
    "pwLat": "1.521559",
    "citizensAndScores": [
      {
        "name": "Steven Wagner",
        "peaceScore": 65
      },
      {
        "name": "Christine Jones",
        "peaceScore": 64
      }
    ],
    "words": "Rayonism",
    "date": "02/04/2022 16:55:39",
    "battery": 5,
    "temperature": 30
  },
...
  {
    "pwId": 47,
    "pwLong": "5.865177",
    "pwLat": "0.459872",
    "citizensAndScores": [
      {
        "name": "Lillian Sargent",
        "peaceScore": 42
      },
      {
        "name": "Debra Santo",
        "peaceScore": 21
      }
    ],
    "words": "defecography",
    "date": "02/04/2022 16:55:40",
    "battery": 19,
    "temperature": 37
  }
]
```

And my Message and Citizens case class are as following :

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Reads, __}
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Citizens(name: String, peaceScore: Int)
object Citizens {
    implicit val reads: Reads[Citizens] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "peaceScore").read[Int]
        
      )(Citizens.apply _)

  }

case class Message (
      pwId: Int,
    pwLong: Double,
    pwLat: Double,
    citizensAndScores: Array[Citizens],
    words: Array[String],
    date: Long,
    battery: Int,
    temperature: Int,
        )


    object Message {

    implicit val reads: Reads[Message] = (
      (JsPath \ "pwId").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "pwLong").read[Double] and
        (JsPath \ "pwLat").read[Double] and
        (JsPath \ "citizensAndScores").read[Array[Citizens]] and
        (JsPath \ "words").read[Array[String]] and
        (JsPath \ "date").read[Long] and
        (JsPath \ "battery").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "temperature").read[Int]
      )(Message.apply _)

  }
```

Finally, my attempt to create an array of Message case class from my JSON file is as following :

```
package main 

import models.Message

//import models.Message
import play.api.libs.json._

import models.Message


object Main {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val absPath = "./src/main/data/"
    val fileName = absPath + "data_sample.json"

    val test = io.Source.fromFile(fileName).mkString

    val json: JsValue = Json.parse(test)


    implicit val messagesReads = Json.reads[Message]
    val messagesFromJson: JsResult[List[Message]] = Json.fromJson[List[Message]](json)


    println(json)
    println("------------------")
    println(messagesFromJson)

  }
}
```

And for each element of my json file, I get this error :

```
JsError(List(((0)/pwLat,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),List()))), ((0)/date,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),List()))), ((0)/pwLong,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),List()))), ((0)/words,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),List()))), ((1)/pwLat,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),List()))), ((1)/date,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),List()))), ((1)/pwLong,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),List()))), ((1)/words,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),List())),
...
```

I'm really stuck with this error, so any help will appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

`pwLat` is not a number, but a string (e.g `"pwLat": "1.521559",`).

So either update the type, or use a custom `Reads`.

```
(JsPath \ "pwLat").read(Reads[Double] {
  case JsString(repr) => JsResult.fromTry(Try(repr.toDouble))
  case _ => JsError("error.expected.string")
})
```